# lucene query's term documents

Tags: lucene

im beginer with lucene, i tried without success find the class that return for each term in a query the relevant documents array

to be more accurate, where can i find the code that decide if document is relevant or not for a given query

i will be grateful for guiding

Comment: It seems to me that you don't understand how Lucene search actually works. What task do you try to solve?

Comment: i want to implement zig-zag join on conjunctive querys

Answer (score 2):

The problem with results is that Lucene collects not all, but **only N top results** (N is set by you). And this is a good idea, since it reduces time for search process heavily, yielding only results you may be interested. Though you can set N to some very big number, make one search for each term in query and then combine results, I actually do not recommend doing this.

On the other hand, You can combine your terms **before searching**, not after. I'm not familiar with zig-zag join, but most probably you'll have to create new syntax for **query** and force `QueryParser` use your `ZigZagQuery` (or whatever you call it). For examples of implementation see [Query subclasses](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Query.html) source code.